# NodeJS parsing json objects from twitter

Tags: json, node.js, twitter

I am looking to grab some information from the data twitter  provides.  Im looking to extract all the screen names that come out of this object.

```
   T.get('followers/list', { screen_name: 'screenname' },  function (err, data, response) {
    console.log(data);
   });
```

You will receive this in the object :

```
   { users:
      [ { id: 1234,
          id_str: '1234',
          name: 'Name',
          screen_name: 'screenName123',
          location: '....',
          profile_location: null,
          description: '....',
          url: '...',
          entities: [Object],
          protected: false,
          followers_count: 1751,
          friends_count: 2001,
          .
          .
          .
          .
          . } ] }
```

How can I abstract just `screen_name` out of this object.  `data.users.screen_name`  returns undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the console output, `data.users` is an array. So if you want the `screen_name` of the first element then just use: `data.users[0].screen_name`

Comment: thank you that helped me allot. missed that array;) was driving me mental.. cheers!!